# ClientError: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm creating an AWS Lambda Function that tries to download a file (s3.download_file) to a temp dir that I create using the *tempfile* library from Python (3.6). Then, I make some transformations to the file and I need to upload it (s3.upload_file) again. I'm confident about the life cycle from my temp dir, when the Lambda finish its job, the temp dir is going to destroy itself. The Lambda returns an error related to forbidden HeadObject operation. The exact error is:

"An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden"

How can I debug this error? I already checked several sources, some of them talk about adjusting policies, check permissions, but my question is, there is some step by step (that AWS in its documentation doesn't have), that allows me to survive to this problem?

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't worked with roles, only with users. That's the error. Just for test I added full access to user and role either and it's working!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your API calls to S3 are made using AWS credentials. If you want to invoke the HTTP HEAD (or [HeadObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_HeadObject.html)) operation on an S3 object then your credentials need to have permission for the S3 object in question.

Check the IAM policies associated with the [IAM role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles.html) that the Lambda function is using. You need the `s3:GetObject` permission.

Note one additional thing with HeadObject: if the object you request does not exist, the error that S3 returns depends on whether or not you also have the `s3:ListBucket` permission:

- If you have the s3:ListBucket permission on the bucket, S3 returns an HTTP status code 404 ("no such key") error
- If you don’t have the s3:ListBucket permission, S3 returns an HTTP status code 403 ("access denied") error

Here's an example of an S3 policy that would allow the S3 `GetObject` action against all objects in `mybucket` and also allow `ListBucket` on `mybucket`:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: this is not right because `HeadObject` isn't a supported permission

Comment: @wawawa wow, not sure how it went unnoticed all this time. Thanks, I've corrected and enhanced the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error, when trying to upload from local machine. Reason - luck of permissions. Same code on server works fine