# botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden while using local mode in AWS SageMaker

Tags: python, pytorch, amazon-sagemaker

```py
trainer = PyTorch(
    entry_point="train.py",
    source_dir= "source_dir",  # directory of your training script
    role=role,
    framework_version="1.5.0",
    py_version="py3",
    instance_type= "local",
    instance_count=1,
    output_path=output_path,
    hyperparameters = hyperparameters
)
```

This code is running SageMaker NoteNook instance.

Error

```
Creating dsd3faq5lq-algo-1-ouews ... 
Creating dsd3faq5lq-algo-1-ouews ... done
Attaching to dsd3faq5lq-algo-1-ouews
dsd3faq5lq-algo-1-ouews | 2022-11-10 05:39:26,444 sagemaker-training-toolkit INFO     Imported framework sagemaker_pytorch_container.training
dsd3faq5lq-algo-1-ouews | 2022-11-10 05:39:26,475 sagemaker-training-toolkit INFO     No GPUs detected (normal if no gpus installed)
dsd3faq5lq-algo-1-ouews | 2022-11-10 05:39:26,494 sagemaker_pytorch_container.training INFO     Block until all host DNS lookups succeed.
dsd3faq5lq-algo-1-ouews | 2022-11-10 05:39:26,507 sagemaker_pytorch_container.training INFO     Invoking user training script.
dsd3faq5lq-algo-1-ouews | 2022-11-10 05:39:26,673 sagemaker-training-toolkit ERROR    Reporting training FAILURE
dsd3faq5lq-algo-1-ouews | 2022-11-10 05:39:26,674 sagemaker-training-toolkit ERROR    framework error: 
dsd3faq5lq-algo-1-ouews | Traceback (most recent call last):
dsd3faq5lq-algo-1-ouews |   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_training/trainer.py", line 85, in train
dsd3faq5lq-algo-1-ouews |     entrypoint()
dsd3faq5lq-algo-1-ouews |   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_pytorch_container/training.py", line 121, in main
dsd3faq5lq-algo-1-ouews |     train(environment.Environment())
dsd3faq5lq-algo-1-ouews |   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_pytorch_container/training.py", line 73, in train
dsd3faq5lq-algo-1-ouews |     runner_type=runner_type)
dsd3faq5lq-algo-1-ouews |   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_training/entry_point.py", line 92, in run
dsd3faq5lq-algo-1-ouews |     files.download_and_extract(uri=uri, path=environment.code_dir)
dsd3faq5lq-algo-1-ouews |   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_training/files.py", line 131, in download_and_extract
dsd3faq5lq-algo-1-ouews |     s3_download(uri, dst)
dsd3faq5lq-algo-1-ouews |   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_training/files.py", line 167, in s3_download
dsd3faq5lq-algo-1-ouews |     s3.Bucket(bucket).download_file(key, dst)
dsd3faq5lq-algo-1-ouews |   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 246, in bucket_download_file
dsd3faq5lq-algo-1-ouews |     ExtraArgs=ExtraArgs, Callback=Callback, Config=Config)
dsd3faq5lq-algo-1-ouews |   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 172, in download_file
dsd3faq5lq-algo-1-ouews |     extra_args=ExtraArgs, callback=Callback)
dsd3faq5lq-algo-1-ouews |   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto3/s3/transfer.py", line 307, in download_file
dsd3faq5lq-algo-1-ouews |     future.result()
dsd3faq5lq-algo-1-ouews |   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/s3transfer/futures.py", line 106, in result
dsd3faq5lq-algo-1-ouews |     return self._coordinator.result()
dsd3faq5lq-algo-1-ouews |   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/s3transfer/futures.py", line 265, in result
dsd3faq5lq-algo-1-ouews |     raise self._exception
dsd3faq5lq-algo-1-ouews |   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/s3transfer/tasks.py", line 255, in _main
dsd3faq5lq-algo-1-ouews |     self._submit(transfer_future=transfer_future, **kwargs)
dsd3faq5lq-algo-1-ouews |   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/s3transfer/download.py", line 343, in _submit
dsd3faq5lq-algo-1-ouews |     **transfer_future.meta.call_args.extra_args
dsd3faq5lq-algo-1-ouews |   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
dsd3faq5lq-algo-1-ouews |     return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
dsd3faq5lq-algo-1-ouews |   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 676, in _make_api_call
dsd3faq5lq-algo-1-ouews |     raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
dsd3faq5lq-algo-1-ouews | botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
dsd3faq5lq-algo-1-ouews | 
dsd3faq5lq-algo-1-ouews | An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
dsd3faq5lq-algo-1-ouews exited with code 1
1
Aborting on container exit...
```

The same code worked a couple of days back but it is not working from yesterday onwards.

```
Sagemaker Version: 2.115.0
```

I tried changing the SageMaker version to 2.0 but to no avail.

I also uploaded training code on s3 and use s3_uri in "source_dir" but still got the same error.

The problem only occurs while using `instance_type = "local"`
It works perfectly fine if I use a remote instance such as `instance_type = "ml.c4.xlarge"`

I also tried uploading and downloading objects directly from S3 using boto3 and it worked perfectly fine.
eg;

```py
session = boto3.Session()
s3 = session.resource('s3')
s3_obj = s3.Object(bucket, data_key)
s3_obj.put(Body=data)
```

```py
s3client = boto3.client('s3')
response = s3client.get_object(Bucket= bucket, Key= data_key)
body = response['Body'].read()
```

The above code works perfectly fine in same instance.
I am not sure but if it was just an issue with permission, wouldn't the above code also not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code to below, replacing Sagwmaker.pytorch.Pytorch with sagemaker.estimator.Estimator, providing reference to the relevant Docker Image URI.

```py
from sagemaker.estimator import Estimator

TRAIN_IMAGE_URI= "763104351884.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/pytorch-training:1.12.1-cpu-py38"

trainer = Estimator(
    image_uri = TRAIN_IMAGE_URI,
    entry_point="train.py",
    source_dir="source_dir",  # directory of your training script
    role=role,
    base_job_name = base_job_name,
    instance_type= "local",
    instance_count=1,
    output_path=output_path,
    hyperparameters = hyperparameters
)
trainer.fit()
```

This seems to work perfectly in my case.
Although I still do not understand why.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the code worked until a few days ago does not make the problem reproducible.

At this point, **it is strictly dependent on the settings related to your AWS account**.

Looking at the error log, it appears that you do not have **access permissions to the S3 bucket**.

Look at this question, it talks about this very same error:
[ClientError: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60365089/clienterror-an-error-occurred-403-when-calling-the-headobject-operation-forb)

> Check the [IAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles.html) policies associated with the IAM role that the Lambda
> function is using.

Comment: I have edited the question. Can you please look at it again.

Comment: @bhanpuramufaddal Thank you for the clarification, however the problem seems to come back to the same point. You can see an [open issue](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/discussions/2388) on the official sagemaker-python-sdk repo.